# Python3 - tkinter importing and using module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-import, python-module

I am having trouble importing and using a module I have created. I have patcher.py and I would like to import modules from patches.py but I get an error when trying to import and use disable_removecd. I am now a little confused on how to set it up properly and how to import and use it correctly.

patcher.py

```
#import the tkinter module
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import bsdiff4
from patches import *

#bsdiff4.file_patch(dst, dst, patch)

#create a new class
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid(row = 2, sticky = W+E+N+S)
        #,padx=300
        cmexecutable = askopenfilename()
        print(cmexecutable)
        self.mainmenu()

    def mainmenu(self): 

        self.logo = PhotoImage(file='logo.gif')
        self.image = Label(self, image=self.logo)
        self.image.grid(columnspan = 2)
        self.image.configure(background='black')

        #self.bttn1 = Button(self, text = 'Country Specific')
        self.bttn1 = Button(self, text = 'Disable Remove CD Message')
        self.bttn1['command'] = disable_removecd(self)
        self.bttn1.grid(columnspan = 2 ,sticky = W+E+N+S)
```

patches.py

```
from patcher import *

def disable_removecd():

    offset1 = 0x42a98b
    offset2 = 0x42a98c
    offset3 = 0x42a98d
    offset4 = 0x42a98e
    offset5 = 0x42a98f
    offset6 = 0x42e400
    offset7 = 0x42e401
    offset8 = 0x42e402
    offset9 = 0x42e403
    offset10 = 0x42e404

    newvalue1 = b'\x90'
    newvalue2 = b'\x90'
    newvalue3 = b'\x90'
    newvalue4 = b'\x90'
    newvalue5 = b'\x90'
    newvalue6 = b'\x90'
    newvalue7 = b'\x90'
    newvalue8 = b'\x90'
    newvalue9 = b'\x90'
    newvalue10 = b'\x90'

    with open(cmexecutable, 'r+b') as victim:
        victim.seek(offset1)
        victim.write(newvalue1)
        victim.seek(offset2)
        victim.write(newvalue2)
        victim.seek(offset3)
        victim.write(newvalue3)
        victim.seek(offset4)
        victim.write(newvalue4)
        victim.seek(offset5)
        victim.write(newvalue5)
        victim.seek(offset6)
        victim.write(newvalue6)
        victim.seek(offset7)
        victim.write(newvalue7)
        victim.seek(offset8)
        victim.write(newvalue8)
        victim.seek(offset9)
        victim.write(newvalue9)
        victim.seek(offset10)
        victim.write(newvalue10)
```

When I run patcher.py I get this error:

```
self.bttn1['command'] = disable_removecd(self)
NameError: name 'disable_removecd' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line in `patches.py` causes a cyclic import.

```
from patcher import *
```

I think you used that line to use `cmexecutable` in the `disable_removecd` function. Remove the above line. And pass the value of `cmexecutable` explicitly.

*patcher.py*:

```
...

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid(row=2, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        cmexecutable = askopenfilename()
        self.mainmenu(cmexecutable)

    def mainmenu(self, cmexecutable): 
        self.logo = PhotoImage(file='logo.gif')
        self.image = Label(self, image=self.logo)
        self.image.grid(columnspan=2)
        self.image.configure(background='black')

        self.bttn1 = Button(self, text = 'Disable Remove CD Message')
        self.bttn1['command'] = lambda: disable_removecd(cmexecutable)
        # ^^ set up callback instead of calling it immediately using `lambda`.
        self.bttn1.grid(columnspan=2 ,sticky=W+E+N+S)
```

---

The function `disable_removecd` in `patches.py` should be modified to accept `cmexecutable` as a parameter:

```
def disable_removecd(cmexecutable):
    ....
```

Comment: I make these changes but when I click on bttn1 I get: `File "cmpatcherv002.py", line 37, in <lambda>
    self.bttn1['command'] = lambda: disable_removecd(cmexecutable)
TypeError: disable_removecd() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: @José, I forgot to mention that `disable_removecd` also should be modified. I updated the answer to include it.

Comment: Seems to work now. I changed `def disable_removecd(self):` and with `open(self, 'r+b') as victim:` Is this correct? Also should I be using `self.offset1` ?

Comment: @José, `self` is not recommend name for the parameter because `self` is used as the first parameter of the instance method. But the function `disable_removecd` is not a method.

Comment: @José, You don't need to qualify `offset1`, `offset2`, ... because they are local variables in the same function.